# Problema al hacer update ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo una tabla afiliados y una tabla persona, estoy teniendo problemas al querer editar cualquier campo de un afiliado ya que me sale el siguiente error:

> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_people_on_cui" DETAIL: Key (cui)=(20223844902) already exists. : INSERT INTO "people" ("fullname", "first_name", "last_name", "dob", "gender", "cui", "dni", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"

A lo que entiendo parece que intenta hacer un insert en lugar de un update y como ya existe el 'cui' sale que esta duplicado el valor.

Mi método update es el siguiente:

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @affiliate.update(affiliate_params)
    format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @affiliate], notice: t('admin.affiliates.flash.update.success') }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: [:admin, @affiliate] }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @affiliate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def affiliate_params
  params.require(:affiliate).permit(:code,
                                    :affiliate_type_id,
                                    :active,
                                    :start_at,
                                    :expiration_at,
                                    :confirmation_code,
                                    :card_number,
                                    :person_attributes => [
                                      :first_name,
                                      :last_name,
                                      :dob,
                                      :gender,
                                      :dni,
                                      :cui
                                    ])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes agregar el `:id` en `person_attributes`, además en tu formulario de la vista (si es que no lo has hecho ya).
Sin el id, rails no va a saber cual es la persona a actualizar.

Comment: Efectivamente era ese el problema, se me paso por encima. Muchas gracias por la ayuda de siempre!  Me faltaba el ':id' en el controlador. Saludos.